# Spark: unable to load parquet files from HDFS until "put" them into hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet, webhdfs

I have a c# application that creates and upload parquet files to a remote HDFS. If I copy the file using scp to a target machine with a HDFS client installed  and then "hdfs put" the file into HDFS, spark can read the file correctly.

If I upload the file directly to HDFS from the client application using curl against webhdf services, I get the following error from Spark when trying to read the parquet file:

> > > df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 303, in parquet
> > >           return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
> > >         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
> > >         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
> > >           raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
> > >       pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'

If I extract both files (the scp uploaded one and the file uploaded via curl) to the local filesystem and make a binary diff between the files, the diff does not show any difference. If I put the file again into HDFS (the one that was uploaded using curl and webhdfs), then Spark can read well the parquet file.

It's something like the "hdfs put" made some kind of magic to make spark read well the parquet file.

What could be happening? Thanks

UPDATE: If I get to local a directory with several parquets and put it at once again into HDFS, it does not work, I have to put the parquet files one by one to make spark read them

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the webhdfs services puts the file under the same path (/tmp/test.parquet)? In other words, can you download the file (that has been uploaded via webhdfs) with the hdfs client (hdfs get)?

Bests,
fej

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm doing the get before making the binary diff between the two files.

Comment: Weird. I can think two things: 1) Some synchronization error. The file is not available yet when you try to run the spark program. Did you try to run it after a successful hdfs-client-get? 2) Something messed up with the permissions and visibility. You can list the HFDS content from the spark program through the Java Hadoop API. This is the same, that is used by spark.

Comment: It still fails after a succesful hdfs -get, I will study if it could be some permissions issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the reason of the error. Name of the uploaded files started with "_" character. It was the reason why spark wasn't able to load the parquet file.